# I am getting this error: uncaught (in promise) TypeError: userData.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios, vuex

I am getting this error: uncaught (in promise) TypeError: userData.filter is not a function. I have a table with data and this data has different columns or properties. I store this object array data in my vuex store and get it from my component and filter it through my component

```
 <tr v-for="report in filteredReports" :key="report.id">
          <td></td>

          <td>
            <div v-show="report.edit !== 'serialNum'">
              <label @dblclick="report.edit = 'serialNum'">
                @{{ report.serialNum }}
              </label>
            </div>
            <input
              name="serialNum"
              v-show="report.edit == 'serialNum'"
              v-model="serialNum"
              v-on:blur="report.edit = ''"
              @keyup.enter="report.edit = ''"
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <div v-show="report.edit !== 'reporter'">
              <label @dblclick="report.edit = 'reporter'">
                @{{ report.reporter }}
              </label>
            </div>
            <input
              name="reporter"
              v-show="report.edit == 'reporter'"
              v-model="report.reporter"
              v-on:blur="report.edit = ''"
              @keyup.enter="report.edit = ''"
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <div v-show="report.edit !== 'location'">
              <label @dblclick="report.edit = 'location'">
                @{{ report.location }}
              </label>
            </div>
            <input
              name="location"
              v-show="report.edit == 'location'"
              v-model="report.location"
              v-on:blur="report.edit = ''"
              @keyup.enter="report.edit = ''"
            />
</td>
```

This is my script for my component

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "ReportComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      editMode: false,
      editedUser: null,
      searchId: "",
      searchSerial: "",
      searchName: "",
      searchLocation: "",
      searchStatus: "",
      searchComptyp: "",
      searchDate: "",

      userData: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    serialNum: {
      get() {
        console.log(this.$store.getters["getReport"]("5CDN098767"));
        return this.$store.getters["getReport"]("5CDN098767");
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit("updateMessage", value);
      },
    },

    filteredReports() {
      let userData = this.$store.state.reports.reports;
      console.log("user", userData);
      console.log("searchName", this.searchName);

      return userData
        .filter((report) => !report.serialNum.indexOf(this.searchSerial))
        .filter((report) => !report.reporter.indexOf(this.searchName))
        .filter((report) => !report.status.indexOf(this.searchStatus));
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("fetchReports");
  },
  methods: {
    saveData() {},
  },
};
</script>
```

As You can see in my component I am using getters and setters for two way computed binding and this is causing the error. At first I thought my filtering code was causing the  problem so I had this code instead:

```
let userData = this.$store.state.reports.reports;
      console.log("user", userData);
      console.log("searchName", this.searchName);

      return this.filterProductsBySerial(
        this.filterProductsByName(this.filterProductsByCategory(userData))
      );
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("fetchReports");
  },
  methods: {
    filterProductsBySerial(reports) {
      return reports.filter(
        (report) => !report.serialNum.indexOf(this.searchSerial)
      );
    },

    filterProductsByName(reports) {
      return reports.filter(
        (report) => !report.reporter.indexOf(this.searchName)
      );
    },

    filterProductsByCategory(reports) {
      return reports.filter(
        (report) => !report.status.indexOf(this.searchStatus)
      );
    },
```

No success. I figured that the problem was in my store that either I needed to filter in my store or that need to update my updateMessage mutation

```
export default {
  state: {
     strict: true,
    reports: [],
    newArr:[]
  
  },
  getters: {
    getReport: (state) => (serialNum) => {
      console.log(state.reports)
    return state.reports.find(x => x.serialNum === serialNum)
    },
    reported: (state) => state.reports,
    //        getQuoteById: (state) => (id) => {
    //   console.log(state.quotes)
    //   return state.quotes.find(quote => quote.id === id)
    // }, 
},
    actions: {
        async fetchReports({ commit }) {
            const response = await axios.get(
                'http://localhost:3000/reported'
            );

            commit('setReports', response.data);
        },
    },
    mutations: {
      setReports: (state, payload) => (state.reports = payload),
    updateMessage: (state, payload) => (state.reports = payload)
   
    },
}
```

So I changed my updateMessage to this  `updateMessage: (state) => (serialNum) => { console.log(state.reports) return state.reports.find(x => x.serialNum === serialNum) },`
But this did not give any functionality also this would only filter out the array with the given serialNum and really update it. I also tried to change my getter and as you see in my code my getter filters out based on serialNum. I have done more tries and changes but I can not write it all out here.

Json object array before adding it to an array in my store

```
 "reported": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "serialNum": "5CDN098767",
      "reporter": "James Hardy",
      "location": "malmo",
      "damage": "This is broken down",
      "status": "In repair",
      "priority": "5",
      "date": "date",
      " edit": null
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "serialNum": "5CDN098BHBD",
      "reporter": "James Hardy",
      "location": "malmo",
      "damage": "This is broken down",
      "status": "In repair",
      "priority": "5",
      "date": "date",
      " edit": null
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "serialNum": "PX09CTY",
      "reporter": "James Hardy",
      "location": "malmo",
      "damage": "This is broken down",
      "status": "In repair",
      "priority": "5",
      "date": "date",
      " edit": null
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "serialNum": "WC1309NY",
      "reporter": "James Hardy",
      "location": "malmo",
      "damage": "This is broken down",
      "status": "In repair",
      "priority": "5",
      "date": "date",
      " edit": null
    },
```

Comment: Are you sure you need `this.$store.state.reports.reports` and not `this.$store.state.reports`? The double `reports` looks suspicious... Elsewhere you have `state.reports.find`... so `state.reports` is the array, not `state.reports.reports`. BTW, this is very easy to debug. Did you try debugging?

Comment: @trincot I  need the double report or else i get this `Proxy {strict: true, reports: Array(0), newArr: Array(0)}`But only in my computed. everywhere else I don't need it as you said. In my getter it returns the array with the matching serialNum. I updated the question with my json data before i post to store array